# updateMatrixInput not working in observe loop in R shiny

Tags: r, loops, matrix, shiny, observers

I am tryng to update "matrixInput" in R shiny via observe in a lapply loop. However,it doesnt seem to be working. Below is the code.

```
library("shinydashboard")
library("shiny")
library("Rblpapi")
library("shinyMatrix")

ui <- sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    actionButton("addSeries", HTML("Click here to add Series<br/>...")),
  ),
  
  mainPanel(),
  
) #end of UI


server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  observeEvent(input$addSeries, {
    insertUI(
      selector = "#addSeries",
      multiple=TRUE,
      where = "afterEnd",
      ui = tags$hr(tags$div(
        
        
        HTML(paste0("<b>" ,"------DataSet",input$addSeries,"------")),
        
        selectInput(inputId = paste0("SeriesComponent",input$addSeries),
                    label = "select components here",
                    choices = c("hacker","not hacker","old man"),
                    selected="",
                    multiple=TRUE),
                        
        matrixInput(inputId = paste0("SeriesWeights",input$addSeries),
                    label = paste0("Weights for Series", input$addSeries),
                    value = matrix(c(1),1,1),
                    class = "numeric",
                    rows=list(names=TRUE),
                    cols = list(names=TRUE)
        ),
                        
      )#end of tags$div for adding data
      )# end of tags$hr
    )#end of insertUI for adding data
  })#end of observe event for adding data
  
  #lapply to update the Series weights reactively
  
  lapply(seq_along(input$addSeries),

         function(i){
          observe({
             updateMatrixInput(session, inputId=paste0("SeriesWeights",i),
                               value=matrix(input[[paste0("SeriesWeights",i)]], 1, length(input[[paste0("SeriesComponent",i)]]),dimnames=list("Weights",input[[paste0("SeriesComponent",i)]])))
           })

         }#end of function within lapply
  )#end of lapply
  

  
}#end of server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I am expecting the Matrix Inputs to change its elements reactively as i choose the elements under "SeriesComponents". However, I get the below error:

```
Warning: Error in : Can't access reactive value 'addSeries' outside of reactive consumer.
i Do you need to wrap inside reactive() or observer()?
  54: <Anonymous>
Error : Can't access reactive value 'addSeries' outside of reactive consumer.
i Do you need to wrap inside reactive() or observer()?
```

Shouldn't I be able to access input$addSeries outside of the reactive environment?
How should i work around?

Comment: As you are using `input$addSeries`, your `lapply` needs to be inside an `observer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for your lapply

```
 ####lapply to update the Series weights reactively
  observe({
    lapply(seq_along(req(input$addSeries)),

           function(i){
             req(input[[paste0("SeriesWeights",i)]])
             
               updateMatrixInput(session, inputId=paste0("SeriesWeights",i),
                                 value=matrix(input[[paste0("SeriesWeights",i)]], 1, length(input[[paste0("SeriesComponent",i)]]),dimnames=list("Weights",input[[paste0("SeriesComponent",i)]])) )
            
           }#end of function within lapply
    )#end of lapply
  })
```